# Why didn't the apostles keep track of years after Jesus ascension?

Tags: life-of-jesus, apostles

Apart from preaching the good news to the Gentiles and the Jews, did the apostles have a responsibility to keep track of the number of years passed since Jesus Christ was taken up in a cloud to heaven. The Jews had their own calendar and they had a system of tracking the days, months and years. They knew the day Jesus took them to Mount Olives and ascended into heaven. This is because the 2023 years proposed isn't exactly accurate.

Comment: I do not understand this at all. Is it being suggested that apostles were obliged (by whom ?) to introduce a new, global, calendar ? And of what value is it, to know exactly how much time has passed since Ascension ? And  . . . .  the number 2023 celebrates (quite rightly, I suggest) a close approximation to the time of the birth of Jesus of Nazareth, which is an excellent way of recording time since that momentous event.

Comment: @NigelJ, is 2023 AD in the year of our lord measured from his birth or his ascension because during his lifetime here on earth no one celebrated his birth

Comment: AD is Anno Domini, In the year of our Lord, and denotes time from the birth of Jesus of Nazareth. Wikipedia has loads of information about the history of calendars, [Gregorian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar), and so forth.

Comment: @NigelJ, if the apostles kept track of the years since ascension which happened when Jesus was about the age of 33 then we would know the exact year he was born but my question is focusing on whether the apostles had a responsibility of documenting the time since ascension for future generations.

Comment: Well, Jesus apparently did not instruct them to do so. It would seem.

Comment: @NigelJ - I agree. Below I  argue that they believed Jesus had instructed them NOT to do so.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if we had a more detailed account of the number of years that passed in the OP's question. However, it is not fair to compare their situation - or even the accounts in the Book of Acts - to the Jewish calendar. Although Israelite religion did include an account of numbers of years in providential history, this account is rough and often symbolic: 40 years here, 400 years there, 120 years in another place, etc. It is only by the time of the Books of Samuel and Kings that we get specific accounts of the number of years each ruler reigned, but there are still only rare accounts of the amount of time passing between specific events.

The OP says: "The Jews had their own calendar and they had a system of tracking the days." Yes, but the apostles did not think of themselves as establishing a new religion that would last for centuries. Instead, they themselves were Jews and expected Jesus to return very soon, so there was no need keep track of the years. Because they were also warned in Matthew 24:36 that “of that day and hour no one knows, neither the angels of heaven, nor the Son, but the Father alone," they did not think they had a responsibility to keep track of the years. Indeed, they may have felt they had a responsibility to avoid such record-keeping. Instead they should, like the wise virgins of Mt. 25, keep their lamps trimmed and burning in expectation of the Bridegroom's immediate return.

**Conclusion**: Although we today would benefit from have a more detailed record of earliest church history, the apostles - from their point of view - did not have a responsibility to create one. That would be left to Luke in the Books of Acts, and to students of the Bible to discuss for millennia to come.

Comment: He led them out to the mount if Olives and was taken up in a cloud

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, those who saw Jesus Christ ascend visibly up into the sky, till a cloud hid him from sight, would know the exact hour, day and year in the Jewish calendar when that happened. They knew the significance of the 50 day-count till Pentecost, when the Holy Spirit was poured out on them, as Jesus promised would happen "not many days hence" if they waited in Jerusalem (Acts chapter 1).

However, they also would remember what Christ said to them immediately before giving that instruction/promise. They had just asked him if Christ was going to restore again the kingdom to Israel. His answer was neither a "no" nor a "yes".

> "It is not for you to know the times or the seasons, which the Father
> has put in his own power" (verse 7 A.V.)

That, along with Matthew 24:36 and Daniel 12:9, should be enough for all Christians to quit trying to pinpoint years, months and days with regard to Christ, either back then, or into the future. The very fact that controversy still continues to this day as to the exact year of Jesus' birth (let alone the month or the day) serves to show the futility of trying to work out precise dates either for Jesus' time on Earth, or his future return. Oh, yes, there are those who emphatically insist that they ***do*** know how to calculate the exact date of his birth, death and resurrection, but the very fact that the Bible does not state what those are should teach us a vital lesson.

We are not meant to know because nobody's salvation depends on knowing such dates.

Jesus told his followers what to concentrate on until he suddenly returns, coming like a thief in the night. Followers who are getting on with what the Lord requires them to be getting on with shall not be caught unprepared, however. Whenever Christ returns, they will be ready, knowing that he could return any day. By not passing on to posterity a written record of dates and times, those first century Christians showed they understood and believed what Jesus warned them about in Acts 1:7.

No doubt it didn't take long, at the turn of the first century, for some to desire a precise record as they saw the years slipping by and still no return of Christ. But that was why the Apostle John was told to write the book of the Revelation given to him - to prepare Christians to remain expectantly faithful no matter how long the return took. That is why Christianity has just kept growing to this very day. Even if Christ does not come in our lifetime, we will remain expectantly faithful for all of our life.

So, **the answer to the question, *'Did the apostles have a responsibility to keep track of the number of years passed since Jesus Christ was taken up in a cloud to heaven?'* is "No, they did not."** And the ***'Why?'*** has been explained in the previous paragraphs.

Comment: Yes and without faith, you do not please God